# IIS has read only web.config - shared config with azure file storage

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, azure

Something is causing our web.config to be locked as read-only meaning that we can't edit it. According to an Unlock tool, it isn't locked. But as administrator on the box we can't edit it.

We are running on two VMs with IIS Shared Config. The website files and IIS config are located on a shared file storage, using Azure File. This is accessed using UNC references.

This is not all the time, we have seen it working properly in read write mode only two days ago. But now even after IIS resets and VM reboots (staggered on both VMs) it won't go back to read write. Something seems to have turned it read only.

This applies to web.config and another config file which is referenced by that file.

This happened before on another site on same servers and we fixed it by copying all the files and recreate the site in IIS. Is there a better way? What causes this?